# Copying text file to a variable in Bash

Tags: bash, file, variables, text

Is there a way to copy the content of a text file to a variable in Bash?

Let's say I have a file containing some text, and I would like to modify text but not a file itself. How can I copy the content of this file to a variable, and then modify the variable?

Comment: You can use utilities like `sed` to modify the file contents without modifying the actual file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very clear on what you're asking, but I think this is what you're after.

if you have `file.txt`, you can do this

`var1=$(cat /path/to/file.txt)`

you can then manipulate it how you please.

edit:

You can access the variable by `$var1`, i.e. `echo "$var1"`